# Correlation between two binary images

Tags: python, image-processing, correlation

I need to calculate the correlation between two binary images in Python. The script should return 1 if the matrices are identical, and 0 if they are totally uncorrelated. It should be something similar to `corr2` in Matlab (http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/corr2.html). Here is the test I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

A = np.matrix('1 0; 1 0')
B = np.matrix('1 0; 1 0')
cor = signal.correlate2d(A, B)
print cor
```

How could I get a single value instead of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `corrcoef`. It will return a 2*2 matrix with the non-diagonal element correlation coefficient between the two matrices:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('1 1; 1 0')
B = np.matrix('1 0; 1 0')
cor = np.corrcoef(A.reshape(-1), B.reshape(-1))[0][1]
print cor
```

Comment: Thanks @lennon310. Is there a way to pass from the `corrcoef` matrix to a single value?

Comment: Thank you albus. You can just select the [0,1] element of the matrix.

Comment: @albus_c I used a dirty method by reshaping the matrix to a vector, please see my update. Thanks

Comment: This will give a number between -1 and 1.  @albus_c do you want a number strictly between 0 and 1?

Comment: @lennon310 Problem solved! Paul I think I'm fine with [-1;1], thanks

Comment: @Paul, I think for the binary images, the output is [0,1]; if there are negative elements in the matrix, corr2 in matlab also gives you negative correlation coefficients. Thanks.